# Html Slim attributes without values

Tags: html, slim-lang

There is the following SLIM code:

```
input international-phone-number="international-phone-number" type="text"
```

It code generates the HTML code:

```html
<input international-phone-number="international-phone-number" type="text"></input>
```

But I need to get:

```html
<input international-phone-number type="text"></input>
```

How can I output an HTML attribute without a value?

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `input international-phone-number type="text"` or `input international-phone-number="" type="text"`?

Comment: Of course, it doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

There have been multiple [issue reports](https://github.com/slim-template/slim/issues/480) on GitHub on this, and they have implemented support for valueless attributes (not sure if it's still in the temple version, if it is you'll have to use [this](https://github.com/judofyr/temple)). You'll need to do the following:

```
input(international-phone-number type="text")
```

Make sure you also set the `:format` to `:html` like this:

```
slimrb --option format=:html
```